# В чем заключается ошибка? 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python

Здраствуйте! Не могу понять, почему не работает этот участок кода:

```
import decimal
salary = decimal(input())

incomeTax = salary / 100 * 18
militaryTax = incomeTax / 100 * 1.5

result = salary - incomeTax - militaryTax


print('Result:', result)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "43.py", line 4, in <module>
    salary = decimal(input())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/6.4.php

Comment: Спасибо, но яснее не стало. Не могу сам разобраться где я сделал ошибку

Comment: `salary = decimal.Decimal(input())`

Comment: либо from decimal import Decimal :)

Comment: К сожалению опять ничего не помогло, но появился новый код ошибки:
` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "43.py", line 7, in <module>
    militaryTax = incomeTax / 100 * 1.5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import decimal
salary = decimal.Decimal(input())

incomeTax = salary / 100 * 18
militaryTax = incomeTax / 100 * decimal.Decimal(1.5)

result = salary - incomeTax - militaryTax


print('Result:', result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Участок кода не работает из-за того, что вы миксуете класс float и класс decimal, что делать не рекомендуется. То есть или все во флоате или все в децимале лучше использовать.

```
import decimal

d = decimal.Decimal('10.5')
f = float('10.5')
print(d == f) # True


d = decimal.Decimal('10.5557')
f = float('10.5557')
print(d == f) # False
```